# Retrieving data from API

Tags: jquery, xml, json, api, curl

Im trying to retrieve data from an API using jQuery that returns the message in an XML format. Im more confused to what value to get from the API to put into my function, because when I run it through CURL it tells me that the application is JSON, but in developer tools I get it telling me its XML.

http://cloudandproud.cloudapp.net/api/values?id=42 is the API

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the curl command you are using... are you sending an accept header

Comment: curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://cloudandproud.cloudapp.net/api/values?id=42

im just confused really and i dont know what to call the data in to my script

Comment: whether your script will be running on the same domain or in a different one

Comment: running from a different domain, im using php proxy to get past the cross-domain stuff

Comment: In your curl command you are asking to return a json data that is why you are getting json formatted data, in browser since the `Accept` header is not passed the server is returning the default format which is the xml in this case.... try the json command `curl -i -H "Accept: application/xml" cloudandproud.cloudapp.net/api/values?id=42`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your curl command you are asking to return a json data(`Accept: "application/json"`) that is why you are getting json formatted data, in browser since the Accept header is not passed the server is returning the default format which is the xml in this case....

For xml output pass the `Accept` header as `application/xml`

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/xml" cloudandproud.cloudapp.net/api/values?id=42
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, i only learnt about curl the other day